# Features extraction using Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, matlab-figure, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am new in matlab software so may be my question is simple but I did not found an answer for my my question, I calculated some statistical features for several time series signals , Then I calulate the average of each one of the feature ex: average of mean, average of median, now I want to draw these results (av. of mean ,....) as a new signal , How I can that ?

Comment: [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have 5 signals and you have calculated mean and median for each one, you can store calculations in vectors mean and median like in the code below.
Then you need to use plot function to draw median and mean as new signals.

```
mean=[1.2, 4, 6, -7, 3.2];
median=[1.11, 3, 5, -2.6, 8];
N=1:5;

figure;
plot(N,mean,'r',...
     N,median,'b');
```

Mean will be plotted in red and median in the blue line.